# KNMI DB query to Oracle table

Tags: knime

I can share any screenshot because of restriction but I am trying to find a way how to avoid row by row inserting in KNIME. for example I have Table Creator with one column Val. where I have 10 values. DB Writer but will always issues 10 inserts behind the scenes I think. At least if I have 1000 values then I can see how it slowly reads row by row and it takes too much time.

it is like
insert into table value (val1);
insert into table value (val2);

which is very slow in Oracle either. is not like insert into select or forall